# What's the meaning of the line "9 Parts of Desire" in this song?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics, trickbaby

There is a partially Hindi (there is only a couple of lines in Hindi; rest is in English) song titled as "9 Parts of Desire". Here is the YouTube link to that song.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBp4Y7CjRwg

The song has lyrics like,

> Parde ke peeche (Behind the veil)
>
> Burns a fire.
>
> Parde ke peeche (Behind the veil)
>
> **9 parts of desire.**

What does exactly this line mean? What is it referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe, from what I'm reading, that [Ali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali), the first Shi'a imam, said,

> Almighty God has created the sexual desire in ten parts; then He gave nine parts to women and one to men

I believe this can be found in the [*Wasā'il al-Shīʿa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Was%C4%81%27il_al-Sh%C4%AB%CA%BFa) volume 14, page 40; I could not come across a copy of this online so I cannot confirm that citation. But that does seem to be where that line comes from.

[Elsewhere](https://books.google.com/books?id=sSxZCAAAQBAJ&pg=PT47&dq=wasa%27il+vol+14&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpjtLN1JTbAhUGn1MKHUsVBcgQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=nine%20parts&f=false) it quotes the rest of the hadith this is from as

> And if the Almighty God had not given the women equal parts of shyness, then each man would have nine women related to him.

It should be noted that this book also seems to cite volume 14, page 40 as the source for this.